# find a span for a polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra

$$\{ a{x^3} + b{x^2} + ( - a - b)x\}  = sp\{ {x^3} - x,{x^2} - x\}$$

How do you find the span of a polynomial?
I'd be glad if you could explain what was done in the example above.

thanks

Comment: A polynomial $a_0 + a_1x + a_2x^2 + a_3x^3$ can, as far as addition is concerned, be thought of as a vector $(a_0, a_1, a_2, a_3)$. In your case, you're interested in the span of $\{(0, -1, 0, 1), (0, -1, 1, 0)\}$ and why said span is $\{(0, -a-b, b, a)\}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The span of the polynomials $x^3 - x$ and $x^2 - x$ is the set of all linear combinations $a(x^3 - x) + b(x^2 - x)$ where $a$ and $b$ are real numbers. Try to multiply out the brackets and see what you get.